# How to "format as table" in Excel or apache POI?

Tags: excel, apache-poi, excel-2007

In Excel 2010 it's possible to "format as table" a group of cells - enabling easy sorting and filtering (Home > Format As Table).

Can I do the same in Apache POI? Alternatively, can one accomplish the above directly in Excel via a macro/formula (as opposed to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or clicking on a toolbar button)?

Answer (score 2):

There's a fairly new feature in POI that may deliver what you need. Grab a recent nightly/svn build (or wait for POI 3.8 beta 3 in a week or so), and take a look at XSSFTable. You should now be able to add one to a sheet, specify the range it applies to (the range you want to be made a table), and that hopefully will do you. It's quite new though, so you may need to join the [POI dev list](http://poi.apache.org/mailinglists.html) and help with the development of the feature if it's not quite there for you!