# How to format an Excel table using formula?

Tags: excel, coldfusion, excel-formula

I'm creating an Excel spreadsheet dynamically from information in my database using ColdFusion.

I discovered that I can insert Excel formulas into cells and they will automatically be executed. I was wondering if it's possible to utilise Excel's '[Format as table](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/format-an-excel-table-HA010013769.aspx)' feature through a formula or macro, or is there another way to do this?

Comment: What does format as table mean?

Comment: Excel styles the table rows in alternating colours and adds a colour scheme. The table headers become clickable allowing you to sort ascending and descending by the column.

Comment: It's probably not possible.  If it was, somebody would have told you how to do it the last time you asked.

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: I think @DanBracuk was referring to your other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237648/format-cfspreadsheet-as-table

Comment: It is not possible with CF's native functions. [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6123904/104223) suggests POI 3.8 added support for that feature, but CF9/10 use an older version (3.6 I think). So that will not help. A macro is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this through a macro like follows

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$D$10"), , xlNo).Name = _
        "Table1"
    Range("Table1[#All]").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9"

End Sub
```

This will format cells A1 through D10 As a Table using the TableStyleLight9 style which is blue by default.

Comment: How could I get this to execute on loading the file? Also is there way to specify 'headers already included'

Comment: I changed the code to show it on Open. If you put it in a sub routine under ThisWorkbook in your vba project with the name signature

Private Sub Workbook_Open() then it will run when the workbook is open. This created the Table with headers for me, but I think that has to do with your table style

Comment: I also find using the Macro Recorder http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/record-and-use-excel-macros-HA001054837.aspx is a good place to start, you can easily customize a generated macro to meet your needs.